# How to insert Foreign Key values from Form Input?

Tags: yesod

Say I have the following relations :

```
    Section 
        name Text 
        UniqueSection name

    Subject
        name Text
        UniqueSubject name

    Faculty
        name Text
        UniqueFaculty name

    Assignment
        section SectionId
        faculty FacultyId
        subject SubjectId
        UniqueAssignment section subject
```

Handler:

```
    postNewAssignmentR :: Handler Html
    postNewAssignmentR = do

    -- don't know what to use instead xxxField for SectionId/FacultyId/SubjectId

            sec <- runInputPost $ ireq xxxField "section"
            fac <- runInputPost $ ireq xxxField "faculty"
            sub <- runInputPost $ ireq xxxField "subject"

            runDB $ insert $ Assignment sec fac sub
            setMessage "Created new Assignment"
            redirect AssignmentsR
```

If "section", "faculty", and "subject" are dropdowns inputs with their corresponding Ids as values(in Text we get from runInputPost), how to convert them to sectionId, facultyId,..etc ?
or  should I go for any other approach to insert foreign keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized you are not generating the forms using Yesod so my original suggestion below may not work. You can probably get the input value as an `Int` and then use `fKey = Key $ PersistInt64 intReturnValue`

**Unsure if the code below will work for your case:**

You can use `selectField` to get a list of Section Names and then populate it in your dropdown -- the values should map to IDs automatically. I don't use Input Forms but guessing something like this should work:

```
<*> ireq (selectField sections) "Section Name"


where
sections = do
    entities <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc SectionName]
    optionsPairs $ map (\e -> (sectionName $ entityVal e, entityKey e)) entities
```

Comment: Can we assume from the accepted answer that selectField works for this case?